# Get JSON Data from AJAX Request and Populate with Random Item

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am attempting to receive JSON data from an AJAX request and then finding a way to show a random item from that. I also want to store this data in `localStorage` so subsequent requests are not sent to the database so that the random item is chosen from `localStorage` once it exists in there.

For example, my JSON data looks like this:

```
{
  "tennis": [
    {
      "Description": "Insert description here", 
      "Address": "24 Fakeville St",
      "Courts": 4
    },
    {
      "Description": "Insert description here", 
      "Address": "18 Fakeville St",
      "Courts": 2
    }
  ], 
  "soccer": [
    {
      "Description": "Insert description here", 
      "Address": "18 Fakeville St",
      "Courts": 1
    }, 
    {
      "Description": "Insert description here", 
      "Address": "18 Fakeville St",
      "Courts": 1
    }
  ],
  "basketball": [
    {
      "Description": "Insert description here", 
      "Address": "4 Fakeville St",
      "Courts": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

My function to get this data is:

```
var data;
function getData() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('myData')) {
        data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myData'));
   } else {
        $.ajax({
        url: '/getMyData',
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
                data = data;
                showContent(data);
            }
        });
    }
    localStorage.setItem('myData', data); 
}
```

Once the data is received, I want to pass it on to the `showContent()` function which will populate it in the HTML. But when I do `console.log(data);`, I see `undefined` in my Chrome console.

```
var tennisArray = [];     
function showContent(data) {
    console.log(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.tennis.length; i++) {
        tennisArray.push(data.tennis[i]);
        // Show random item from the tennis array
    }
}
```

My JSFiddle here is [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/60jzh5fo/).

Comment: First. Set local storage item should be inside Ajax success.  2. Make getData function return data in form of a callback,  and use data inside a callback

Comment: You're probably using stale data from local storage. clear it then test. See if the behavior changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the function in the back end *(getMyData)* to fix what's making that return null and call the function to get a random one from your javascript.

like this:

```
function showContent(aa) {
   for (var i = 0; i < data.tennis.length; i++) {
      tennisArray.push(data.tennis[i]);
      // Show random item from the tennis array
   }
   if(tennisArray.length > 0){
      var random = getRandomInt(0, tennisArray.length - 1);
      console.log(tennisArray[random]);
   }
}
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/60jzh5fo/3/

I've tested the function without your ajax return and it works, but you need to fix whatever is wrong with the back end return.

*you can post more details of your back end and I can update my answer here.*

Comment: When storing to localStorage, should it be `JSON.stringify(data)`? Also, I think I need to call the `showContent(data)` function again once I parse it from localStorage in the if statement.

Comment: This works, thank you! Though I would make the modifications to the code as noted in my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Promise to handle the callback. This way you can resolve it immediately if present in localStorage, or in another cycle if you need to pull it fresh.

```
function getData() {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    if (localStorage.getItem('myData')) {
      deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myData')));
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function (data) {
            localStorage.setItem('myData', JSON.stringify(mockdata));
             deferred.resolve(mockdata);
            }
        });
    }
    return deferred.promise();
}

getData().then(showContent);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/60jzh5fo/4/

Comment: I really like this implementation as well, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Code goes here
function getData(callback) {
  var local = localStorage.getItem('myData');
  if (local) {
    callback(JSON.parse(local), 'local');
  } else {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'data.json',
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(remote) {
        localStorage.setItem('myData', JSON.stringify(remote));
        callback(remote, 'remote');
      }
    });
  }
}

var getJson = function() {
  getData(function(games, source) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      var gameNames = Object.keys(games),
        totalGames = gameNames.length,
        randomGameIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * totalGames),
        randomGame = games[gameNames[randomGameIndex]],
        randomGameItemIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomGame.length),
        randomGameItem = randomGame[randomGameItemIndex];

      console.log("game place: ");
      console.log(randomGameItem);
    }
  });
};
```

here a plunker
[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/z2uuS7?p=preview)

enjoy :)